# Segmentation fault(core dump) in While loop

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop, segmentation-fault, cs50

**Objective:** Print out how much length it takes for the string[i] to reach the same character in the alphabet,

*ex. h = a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h  =====> length = 8  (Capital or not)*

**Problem:** Segmentation fault(Core dump)

**What I tried:** Using debugger. Instead of the while loop stopping in string[i] = 8, it just goes on forever.

**Code:**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int length = strlen(text);

        char alpha[26];
        char beta[26];
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
        {
            alpha[i] = 65 + i;
            beta[i] = 97 + i;
        }
```

**The main problem(I think)**

```
for (int z = 0; z <= length; z++)
            {
            while (text[z] != alpha[i] || text[z] != beta[i])
                {
                    i++;
                }
                printf("%i ", i);
            }
    }
```

Comment: The only way that `while` loop terminates is when `text[z]` is simultaneously  *both* values `alpha[i]` and `beta[i]`.  You want `&&` there; not `||`. Or, use the equivalent negation expression: `while (!(text[z] == alpha[i] || text[z] == beta[i]))`

Comment: @Whoz Craig that worked, thanks!! I also forgot the i = 0.

Comment: `for (int z = 0; z <= length; z++)` It's rare that you actually want to use `<=` for a loop condition. In this case the last iteration will read the terminating 0 at the end of the string.  Not the source of the crash but probably undesired behavior.

Comment: When the code runs you will find that 'h' is found at location 7, not 8... Remember base-zero indexing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I guess your code hasn't been written in C language. Your problem has been caused by the `while` loop condition and not resetting the `i` variable.
The code below is tested.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

    printf("Text: ");

    char text[100];

    scanf("%s", text);

    int length = strlen(text);

    char alpha[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char beta[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int z = 0, i = 0; z < length; z++, i = 0)
    {
        while (!(text[z] == alpha[i] || text[z] == beta[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }

        printf("%i ", i + 1);
    }
}
```